# Python: обработка нажатия/отжатия клавиш в консоли Linux

Tags: python, linux, консоль, клавиатура, обработка

Требуется организовать обработку клавиатуры через консоль. Причем нужно назначить действие на нажатие кнопки и на отжатие. Подобную задачу решает, например, pygame и выглядит это все примерно так:

```
for events in pygame.event.get():
    if events.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        #проверяем конкретную клавишу...
    if events.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        #проверяем конкретную клавишу...
```

Но в pygame захват происходит в созданном окне, а не в консоли.

Comment: попробуйте [`evdev` (ближе к железу только ядро)](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#getting-currently-active-keys) позволяет читать события такие как нажатия клавиш и иногда писать, [к примеру посигналить с помощью  динамика ПК](http://askubuntu.com/a/845970/3712).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Модуль [pynput](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynput) позволяет считывать нажатие и "отжатие" клавиш клавиатуры и мыши, а также контролировать их (т.е. нажимать, двигать и т.д.):

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(
        key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Вывод результата на экран:

```
special key Key.up pressed
Key.up released
special key Key.down pressed
Key.down released
special key Key.right pressed
Key.right released
special key Key.left pressed
Key.left released
alphanumeric key a pressed
'a' released
special key Key.shift pressed
Key.shift released
special key Key.shift pressed
alphanumeric key d pressed
'd' released
Key.shift released
special key Key.alt_l pressed
special key Key.shift pressed
alphanumeric key a pressed
'a' released
Key.shift released
Key.alt_l released
special key Key.space pressed
Key.space released
special key Key.enter pressed
Key.enter released
special key Key.alt_l pressed
Key.alt_l released
```

Comment: А оно на чистой консоли умеет работать?

Comment: @0andriy, что вы понимаете под "чистой консолью"?

Comment: Машину без Хов. Судя по коду там нет такой поддержки.

Comment: @0andriy, не знаю, без иксов не проверял...

Comment: Вот-вот, правильный обработчик должен подписываться на события от `/dev/input/eventX` и мониторить их состояние.