# Как отловить изменения переменной в питоне?

Tags: python, таймер

У меня есть приложение для игры в камень-ножницы-бумага. Для выбора своей фигуры игроку дается 10 секунд, которые отсчитываются в следующем цикле. Мне нужно прервать цикл когда игрок выбрал фигуру, или если по истечении времени он этого не сделал — засчитать поражение. Как мне отловить ввод? Или может есть вариант лучше?

```
import time
global x;
for i in range(10, 0, -1):
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Возможно, вам поможет [ответ на схожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/619993/253429).

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете использовать [select](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html):

```
import sys, select
timeout = 10
i, o, e = select.select( [sys.stdin], [], [], timeout)
if (i):
    print("Вы ввели", sys.stdin.readline())
else:
    print("Вы ничего не ввели")
```

`select` будет ожидать ввод из `sys.stdin`, а когда он последует завершит свою работу. После чего мы из `stdin` и прочитаем то, что туда ввели.

Answer (score 0):

```
import queue

x = queue.Queue(maxsize=1)
try:
    i = x.get(timeout=10)
    print('выбор', i)
except queue.Empty:
    print('поражение')
```